# Trigonometric functions limit to complex infinity

Tags: limits, trigonometry, reference-request

It is well-known that trigonometric functions oscillate on the real axis and the limit does not exist as the argument approaches infinity.

However, I suspect that a limiting value exist if the argument approaches any *complex infinity* that is not real, i.e.
$$\lim_{r\to\infty} f(re^{i\theta})$$ is suspected to exist for $\theta \ne n\pi$, where $f$ is a trigonometric function.

I confirmed it is the case for $\tan (z)$ by decomposing it into real and imaginary parts.

For real part:
$$\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{\sin 2r\cos\theta}{\cos 2r\cos\theta+\cosh 2r\sin \theta}=0$$ which is straightforward.

For imaginary part:
$$\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{\sinh 2r\sin\theta}{\cos 2r\cos\theta+\cosh 2r\sin \theta}=\text{sgn}(\sin\theta)$$

Thus $$\lim_{r\to\infty}\tan(re^{i\theta})= \text{sgn}(\sin\theta)i$$

My questions are:

> 1. Are the above calculations correct?
> 2. Is there an easier way to compute the limit, other than decomposing it into real and imaginary parts?
> 3. Indeed, the limits should be well known. Are there some reliable references that summarize the results for various trigonometric functions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The [Wolfram Functions site](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/) includes limits at $\pm i \infty$ (i.e., $\theta = \pi/2$ or $3 \pi/2$) for all of the trigonometric functions; look under "Specific Values > Values at Infinities".  It does not, however, treat the case for general $\theta$.

Answer (score 4):

You can base all calculations on the fact that $e^{iz} \to \infty$ as $z \to \infty$ with $-\pi+\varepsilon<\arg{z}<\varepsilon$ and $e^{iz} \to 0$ as $z \to \infty$ with $\varepsilon<\arg{z}<\pi-\varepsilon$ (this follows because $\lvert e^{i(x+iy)} \rvert = e^{-y}$). For example,
$$ \tan{z} = \frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{i(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})} = -i\frac{e^{2iz}-1}{e^{2iz}+1}, $$
which tends to $i$ for $\varepsilon<\arg{z}<\pi-\varepsilon$ and $-i$ for $-\pi+\varepsilon<\arg{z}<\varepsilon$.

Similarly, for the other functions, $\cos{z}$ and $\sin{z}$ both tend to $\infty$ for $z \to \infty$ with $\arg{z}$ bounded away from $0$ and $\pi$. Therefore their reciprocals $\csc{z}$ and $\sec{z}$ both tend to $0$ in the same region.

Lastly, $\cot{z}=1/\tan{z}$, so it tends to $-i$ for $\varepsilon<\arg{z}<\pi-\varepsilon$ and $i$ for $-\pi+\varepsilon<\arg{z}<\varepsilon$.

Comment: $e^{iz}$ has its real part and imaginary part are both oscillating as $|z|\to\infty$ with fixed argument. How can you justify your first sentence?

Comment: "$\to \infty$" in the complex plane means that the absolute value tends to infinity; the actual values of the real and imaginary parts are unimportant.  In this case, so long as $y$ is increasing (or decreasing), what $x$ does is totally irrelevant for the limit. If you don't like that, you can show that $|\sin{(x+iy)}|^2 = \sin^2{x}+\sinh^2{y}$, and similarly $|\cos{(x+iy)}|^2 = \cos^2{x}+\sinh^2{y}$, which gives the results for sine, cosine and their reciprocals.

Comment: I asked this question because I need something more precise than just the magnitude. That is why I didn’t mention magnitude in my question at all.