# Asymptotic behavior of trigonometric functions near infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, trigonometry, asymptotics, infinity

This is a follow up of my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812346/trigonometric-functions-limit-to-complex-infinity).

Of course, it makes no sense to discuss the asymptotic behavior of trigonometric functions on the real line, as they oscillates forever and does not even have a limit at infinity.

However, it happens that the limits exist for trigonometric functions with arguments tending to some *complex infinity* which is not real, i.e. 
$$\lim_{r\to\infty}f(re^{i\theta})$$ exists for $\theta\ne n\pi$ where $f$ is some trigonometric functions.

For example 
$$\lim_{r\to\infty}\csc(re^{i\theta})=0$$

Now I become interested in the asymptotic behavior of trigonometric functions near complex infinity. I tried to analyze the functions like $\csc(\frac1z)$ but unfortunately it is not differentiable at $0$ and thus I cannot obtain a Taylor series/Laurent series at $0$.

My question is ($f$ is some trigonometric function)

> If we write $$f(re^{i\theta})\sim l+\text{lower order terms}$$ for large $r$, what are the lower order terms exactly?($l$ is the limit value of $f$ when $r\to\infty$, e.g. for $f=\csc$, $l=0$; $f=\cot$, $l=\pm i$)

Comment: Wouldn’t they be “higher order” terms? (After the change $w=1/z$).

Comment: @LeoBianco Well, I mean the terms that will vanish in the limit. I am not sure which is right.

Comment: The trigonometric functions have essential singularities at $\infty$, and therefore by the Picard theorem, the image under them of any neighborhood of $\infty$ is the entire complex plane, other than possibly two points.

Comment: @PaulSinclair How about for some complex infinity like $\infty e^{i\pi/3}$(not rigorous)? Does the trigonometric function still has an essential singularity at some complex infinity?

Comment: In complex analysis, the standard is to have one infinity, $\infty$, which is approached as one increases without bound in every direction. So it wraps up the complex plane into the Riemann sphere (think of curving the two ends of the real line around until they meet at a single point. The Riemann sphere is the 2D version of the same thing. It is possible to compactify the complex plane by other means such as you describe. But the Reimann sphere is more matural, and gives very nice results. Effectively $\infty$ behaves pretty much like every other point. Only multiplication distinguishes it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair one last question: but the function $\sec$ behaves very differently toward $\infty$ and $i\infty$! Wouldn’t it become ambiguous to just consider one $\infty$?

Comment: And now you have a bit more of an appreciation for what the word "essential singularity" means. Note again the Picard theorem, which states that around an essential singulary, an analytic function *takes on every possible complex value, with at most two exceptions*. This is true no matter how closely around the singularity you look. So it doesn't just behave differently in the positive real and imaginary directions, it behaves differently everywhere. The same is true of all the trig functions, and of $e^z$ (which was used to prove it).